# Api route giving errors if content type is not application/json

Tags: php, laravel, api

I got an issue that seems for web, i am only using Api features on laravel

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined. in file /home/vagrant/code/ruma/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 420
```

this only happens if i do not send application content/type=application/json or Bearer token fails.

it seems to be something with middlewares, here is how i have one example

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors', 'auth:api']], function () {

Route::get('/Sales/All', 'Api\SalesOrderHeaderController@index');
```

middleware cors:

```
class Cors {

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');

}}
```

Comment: Is your login route missing or missing a name? Also check what happens in `/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`

Comment: Yes it is missing for web indeed, but the problem is as this is api only, it should not recall web routes. on the app authenticate i have only

protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('Login');
        }
    }

which does not work if changed

Comment: Then you can probably remove the entire if statement all together?

Comment: Yes! i thought that that was the solution but unfotunately whene deleting the entire statement the same error is given. it seems that some bypass is made that i am not able to find.